# How to properly append move-item results to variable for each item moved in Powershell

Tags: powershell, customization, psobject

I have a collection looping through a foreach statement, creating a table with the information gathered from the childitems, mapped to a table array to begin inserting data into an empty array.

when the file is moved from the source dir to the dest dir. I want to record the move and have it  populate the result to the "File Status" col. The code executes but always skips the first row and leaves the "File Status" col empty for the first item.

What would be a more efficient approach to have it not skip the first item?

```
$childitems = Get-ChildItem "C:\folder1\" -Filter *.csv 

$destpath = "C:\folder2\"

$emptytable = @()

$table1 = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Property = 'Location';Name = 'Store';ID = '1111'}   
)

foreach ($childitem in $childitems) {
    $file = $childitem | get-content
    $fileid = $childitem.PSPath.Split("_")[4] 
    $PropertyName = $table1 | Where-Object {$_.id -eq $fileid}
    $ImportDate = $childitem.BaseName.Split("_")[5]

    
    foreach ($id in $fileid) {     
       $idobj = New-Object PSObject
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Col1" -Value $PropertyName.Property
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "col2" -Value $PropertyName.Name
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Col3" -Value $fileid
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "col4" -Value $file.Count
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "File Status" -Value $Movestatus
       $idobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "col5" -Value $ImportDate
      
       foreach ($item in $childitem) { $Movestatus = ''
          Try 
          {
          Move-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $destpath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
          $Movestatus += 'Moved To Punches'; 
          }
          Catch
          {
          $Movestatus += 'Error Unable to Moved File';
          }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        $emptytable += $idobj
       }
    }
}

$emptytabler code here
```

Comment: VERY unclear.. We have absolutely no idea what variables `$fileid`, `$file`, `$childitem`, `$PropertyName` or `$emptytable` may contain (if anything at all). Furthermore, you are creating a PsObject and set a property `File Status` to the yet to be defined `$MoveStatus`, which apparently should become an array of strings.. Also, if you want to use a `try{..} catch{..}` you need `-ErrorAction Stop` because with `SilentlyContinue` you will not hit the catch block if `Move-Item` errors out.

Comment: Thank you for the response I have added the missing blocks. I was looking to achieve the capture of the move status string in the after the execution of the move-item loop.

Comment: I agree that the question is not clear. It sounds like you have a specific idea about copying files in some way but you may be trying to re-invent the wheel. It might be better to describe your goal/purpose rather than _how_ you think it ought to be accomplished.